# Bootstrap - How to make a login and register page, and then how to make the backend?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a pretty basic knowledge of Bootstrap, but I wanted to know, how might I go about having when login data is typed in, have it call an account, or when registered, how to make an account. Would this require some sort of database, and if so, how would I do this?

EDIT: Took a course on PHP this summer 2014 and understand tons now, thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Boostrap is a front end framework. You need something server side to perform those actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap is a UI toolkit, you are absolutely going to need something beyond it to make a functioning dynamic website. Good news is, there are a ton of things out there to help!

If Python is your game, check out:
[Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/)
[Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)
[Pylons](http://www.pylonsproject.org/)

Or, PHP?
[CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter)
[Symfony](http://symfony.com/)

How about Ruby?
[Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/)
[Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/)

And that's a very small selection.

Not sure how to choose?
[Read more,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks)
[And more,](http://www.bestwebframeworks.com/compare-web-frameworks/)
[And even more,](http://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/)
[And then some!](http://memeburn.com/2011/06/32-web-frameworks-to-choose-from-for-your-next-project/)